# Equivalent for “deal!”

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

For example:

> I'll give you £25 for it
>
> I want 50
>
> 30?
>
> 45
>
> 40?
>
> Deal

Is there a similar word or phrase in French for “deal”? Or you just say something like “I agree” or something like that?

Comment: "Marché conclu" is IMO the most used, but "deal" is also used alot in the canadian french vocabulary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple :

> D'accord !

Courant :

> Marché Conclu !
>   Vendu !

Familier :

> ça marche !
>   On fait comme ça !
>   C'est parti !

Familier spécial:

> Vas-y

(Vas-y à ici la valeur de "C'est parti !", c'est extrêmement familier, c'est un langage particulièrement utilisé par les jeunes)
Vas-y est d'ailleurs souvent utilisé avec "On fait comme ça":

> "Je t'en donne 25$
>   30 ?
>   27 !
>   Vas-y, on fait comme ça !"

Le plus important étant de conclure la transaction avec une poignée de main sincère.

Comment: Chosen as answer for giving the most comprehensive answer. Thanks

Comment: +1 pour "vendu"

Answer (score 5):

***marché conclu!*** is the most appropriate and more widely used. But you can express that in many other ways such as: ***affaire conclue!*** , ***ça marche!***  ... and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You might say "***Tope-là***", offering your hand and the deal is sealed when the other party hit it with his/her own hand à la "give me five."

Answer (score 3):

You can say *D'accord !*  or  *Marché conclu !*

Answer (score 3):

You can also say:

> Va pour *[price reached]* !

Answer (score 2):

As a french canadian, i would say :

> deal

We use the same word. If you want to use a french word you could use

> parfait !

that means "perfect ! " or

> vendu !

that means "sold".

Comment: "Vendu" and "Marché conclu" (lkl's answer) are definitely the most appropriate in this context.

Comment: I agree with Puzzled. But "deal" also works, and "parfait" is not a good answer imo :)